# I want to have a function to retrieve multi-level category data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Currently i have done a function that produce the following result:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "6412d325764891c7d49809a2",
        "category_name": "Computers & Tech",
        "category_child_number": 1,
        "icon_link": "https://media.karousell.com/media/photos/country-collections/icons/main_v2/01_computers_tech.png",
        "children": {
            "_id": "6412d2e6764891c7d49809a1",
            "category_name": "Laptops & Notebooks",
            "category_parent": "6412d325764891c7d49809a2",
            "category_child_number": 2,
            "children": {
                "_id": "6412dca2764891c7d49809a3",
                "category_name": "Test category lv 3",
                "category_child_number": 3,
                "category_parent": "6412d2e6764891c7d49809a1",
                "children": {
                    "_id": "6419558a575c46566854d6b2",
                    "category_name": "Test category lv 9",
                    "category_child_number": 4,
                    "category_parent": "6412dca2764891c7d49809a3",
                    "children": []
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "6413eaa46ccfc392a70b46ab",
        "category_name": "Men's Fashion",
        "category_child_number": 1,
        "icon_link": "https://media.karousell.com/media/photos/country-collections/icons/main_v2/09_mens_fashion.png",
        "children": {
            "_id": "6413ea7b6ccfc392a70b46aa",
            "category_name": "Watches & Accessories",
            "category_child_number": 2,
            "category_parent": "6413eaa46ccfc392a70b46ab",
            "children": {
                "_id": "6413ea676ccfc392a70b46a9",
                "category_name": "Watches",
                "category_child_number": 3,
                "category_parent": "6413ea7b6ccfc392a70b46aa",
                "children": []
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "641d384285b10bb5fdd408eb",
        "category_name": "Computers & Tech 2",
        "category_child_number": 1,
        "icon_link": "https://media.karousell.com/media/photos/country-collections/icons/main_v2/01_computers_tech.png",
        "children": []
    }
]
```

But the result about is not complete compare to wat i wanted to

Below is the code i used to produce the result above:

```
function testRecursion(all_category, category_parent) {
    results = [];

    if (category_parent.category_child_number != 1) {

        all_category.forEach(category => {
            if (category.category_parent != undefined) {

                if (category_parent._id.toString() == category.category_parent.toString()) {
                    console.log("Parent: " + category_parent.category_name)
                    console.log("Child: " + category.category_name )
                    nextParentId = category;
                    category = { ...category._doc, "children": testRecursion(all_category, nextParentId) }
                    console.log(category)
                    results = (category)

                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        nextParentId = category_parent._id;
        category_parent = { ...category_parent._doc, "children": testRecursion(all_category, nextParentId) }
        results = (category_parent)
    }
    
    return results;

}

exports.GetAllCategoryForFilter = async (req, res) => {
    let category_lists = []
    const all_category = await Category.find({})
    const parent_category = await Category.find({ category_parent: { $exists: false } })

    if (parent_category) {
        parent_category.map(async (data) => {
            const response = testRecursion(all_category, data)
            category_lists = [...category_lists, response]

        })
        res.status(200).send(category_lists)
    }
}
```

Image below is a diagram of the database content:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XBNn.png

What i want is to get all content from the image above but the code i done only get Computer & tech->laptop and notebook->lv3->lv9 and does not get other lv's category